# alt tab taken over and trying to get it back

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, tablet

I am running a Galaxy Tab A with Android 6.0.1, but it differs from my cell phone in one regard.

On my cell phone I can press-and-hold the "Home" button center bottom, and get a list of open applications, and can then select one.

On my Tab A, I get Google.

I want to get Google out of the Alt-tab feature WITHOUT removing Google itself from my tablet (as I have Gmail etc.).  How do I do this?

Comment: The feature you describe is the "last used apps". Most recent devices have a separate key assigned to that, looking like two intertwined rectangles. Seeing some screenshots of the Galaxy Tab A, isn't that the key to the left of your "Home button"?

Comment: @Izzy : yes and thanks.  This accordions through them and is better than the alt tab as it gives me a reduced view of the last visual state of the app, AND allows me to close the app with the `X` upper right.  For the record, I had a bazillion of them open. Thanks, I feel much more in control now!

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation! I've converted my comment to an answer. As it solved your issue, please consider "accepting" the answer by clicking the green check-mark next to it – so other "seekers" can identify your answer as having a solution. Thanks – and enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you describe is the "recently used apps". Most recent devices have a separate key assigned to that, looking like two intertwined rectangles:

[image: LRU button]

Seeing some screenshots of the Galaxy Tab A (and finally approved by you), this button is located to the left of the "Home button" on your device.

Comment: In more recent Android versions the icon is just a square, and it's to the right of the home button.

Comment: @KeithThompson That might well be – but on the Galaxy Tab A (which the OP asks for) it looks like that. And when talking about Samsung, the button is always "on the other side".